# How do I put one check mark per section in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

In my tableview i have 4 sections and i need to have 1 check mark in each section. Like so...

- Section 0

  - row 0
  - row 1
  - row 2 /
  - row 3
- Section 1

  - row 0
  - row 1 /
  - row 2

etc..

**numberOfRowsInSection:**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSInteger numberOfRows;
if (section == 0) {
    numberOfRows = 3;
}
else if (section == 1) {
    numberOfRows = 4;
}
else if (section == 2) {
    numberOfRows = 4;
}
else if (section == 3) {
    numberOfRows = 3;
}
return numberOfRows;
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *userChoices = @"UserChoices";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:userChoices];
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:userChoices];

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [mail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [search objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [social objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if (indexPath.section == 3) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [maps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

return cell;

}
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Uncheck the previous checked row
UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
if(self.checkedIndexPath)
{
    uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
    self.checkedIndexPath = nil;
}
else
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
}

// use this to put checkmark on the item
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

The following code gives me a check mark next to a cell within ALL sections of the table. Any body have any ideas?

Comment: Its a little bit better to include the technology in the title or the message as well, not only in tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to keep track of which row is checked on each section:

```
NSMutableDictionary *_checkedRowsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:numberOfSections];

...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([_checkedRowsDict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]]) {
        // Unmark the row found on _checkedRowsDict
        NSNumber *num = [_checkedRowsDict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]];
        int row = [num intValue];
        NSIndexPath *checkIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:indexPath.section];

        UITableViewCell *checkedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:checkIndexPath];
        checkedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    // Mark the selected row
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    // Update _checkedRowsDict
    [_checkedRowsDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]];

    ...

}
```

And something similar to initialize the rows on `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: i cant seem to have any luck with the cellForRowAtIndexPath part haha. Can you please help me with that also :)

Comment: And also, what is the if statement checking?

Comment: I should add, i tried to add the above if statement in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but i get SIGABRT. The Error says: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x15d8012 0x12e5e7e 0x157a0b4 0x2d9c54 0x6e5e 0x2e7f4b 0x2e801f 0x2d080b 0x2e119b 0x27d92d 0x12f96b0 0x110fc0 0x10533c 0x105150 0x830bc 0x84227 0x848e2 0x15a0afe 0x15a0a3d 0x157e7c2 0x157df44 0x157de1b 0x26397e3 0x2639668 0x22d65c 0x26ad 0x25d5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Some cells stay selected, but when i scroll up and down, the app just crashed.

Comment: Basically, the dictionary will have an key/value pair for each section that has been selected where the key is the section and the value is the selected row.  Because is a dictionary, you will only have unique values (only one row per section), the if checks if the section of the selected row is already in the dictionary, if it exists, then it un-selects the row.

Comment: The `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should have the same if to make sure the selected rows stay selected when you scroll up and down. Also, in the crash log, it looks like you are using an array somewhere, maybe that's the reason for the crash, the array you are using doesn't have an object on the row 8 or 9 yet?

Comment: My datasource is coming from an array (Like the names of the items on each cell). my sections are like so...    `varA = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", nil]; etc...` These are NSArray object. And i populate the list like so ... `if (indexPath.section == 0) cell.textLabel.text = [varA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`Should i be defining these as dictionaries also? And also the debugger stops at `checkIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:indexPath.section]; etc...` in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Sorry...The debugger stops here: `UITableViewCell *checkedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:checkIndexPath];`

Comment: I'm not sure why is it stopping, do you have the log?

Comment: Log: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x15d7012 0x12e4e7e 0x15790b4 0x2d8c54 0x6f26 0x2e6f4b 0x2e701f 0x2cf80b 0x2e019b 0x27c92d 0x12f86b0 0x10ffc0 0x10433c 0x104150 0x820bc 0x83227 0x838e2 0x159fafe 0x159fa3d 0x157d7c2 0x157cf44 0x157ce1b 0x26387e3 0x2638668 0x22c65c 0x26ad 0x25d5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)`.The funny thing is that if i scroll very slowly the app doesnt crash, but when i scroll fast it crashes.

Comment: I replaced `checkedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;` with `checkedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;` for the if statement in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This seems to be doing better, but only for the 1st 2 sections. And i also took out `[_checkedRowsDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section]];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I don't think it's necessary to update the dictionary in there since we do that already in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Oh and also the checkmark disappears for the first rows in sections 1 and 2 when i do the above modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Make a NSMutableArray of NSNumbers that contain integer representations of the selected element within the sections that is represented by the element in the array.

You will have to do some more set up but when you check

```
if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
```

you can check

```
if([[yourArrayOfCheckedIndexes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] integerValue] == indexPath.row)
```

Basically you need to store the checked index for every section

Comment: What is integerValue in that condition?

Comment: And for the NSMutableArray of NSNumbers...do i do that like so?: `NSMutableArray *selected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber *number], nil];`

Comment: [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked just fine for me:

-VARIABLES:

```
@property NSInteger checkedCellRow;
@property NSInteger checkedCellSection;
```

-FUNCTIONS:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (checkedCellSection == indexPath.section)
{
if (checkedCellRow == indexPath.row)
{
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
checkedCellRow = indexPath.row;
checkedCellSection = indexPath.section;
[myTable reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I add this to my viewDidLoad and all works fine. Thx.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
NSUInteger i = 2; //Number of section
NSMutableDictionary *_checkedRowsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:i];
...
}
```